How to separate multiple tickers into individual dataframes with yfinance downloaded data
I'm trying to download stock data information using yfinance. Currently, I can successfully download a single ticker using yf.download which returns a dataframe with information I can use. This API also supports downloading multiple tickers at once with a single API call. Due to rate limits on the download API, I need to query all tickers at one time instead of a call for each ticker.
The returned dataframe bunches all of the information together. How can I separate the multiple_df dataframe into individual dataframes as if I pulled a single ticker? I've looked at How to deal with multi-level column names downloaded with yfinance but it doesn't structure the individual dataframe exactly as if you called the API with a single ticker.
Example single ticker for GOOGL
            Adj Close   Close    High     Low    Open    Volume
Date
2022-12-13      95.28   95.63   99.53   95.03   97.76  40593700
2022-12-14      94.73   95.07   96.87   93.60   95.20  28733600
2022-12-15      90.53   90.86   93.64   90.01   93.13  40107000
2022-12-16      89.93   90.26   91.33   89.52   90.76  58011800
2022-12-19      88.12   88.44   90.56   88.21   90.26  29493000
...               ...     ...     ...     ...     ...       ...
2024-12-06     174.51  174.71  175.08  171.86  172.03  21462400
2024-12-09     175.37  175.37  176.26  173.65  173.96  25389600
2024-12-10     185.17  185.17  186.36  181.05  182.85  54813000
2024-12-11     195.40  195.40  195.61  184.85  185.31  67894100
2024-12-12     191.96  191.96  195.18  191.71  194.96  32460315

Current output for multiple downloaded dataframes
Ticker            NVDA                                                  ...        MSFT
Price             Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close  ...        High         Low       Close   Adj Close    Volume
Date                                                                    ...
2022-12-13   18.531000   18.790001   17.711000   18.072001   18.058865  ...  263.920013  253.070007  256.920013  252.771729  42196900
2022-12-14   17.987000   18.252001   17.420000   17.674000   17.661152  ...  262.589996  254.309998  257.220001  253.066925  35410900
2022-12-15   17.146000   17.320000   16.700001   16.952000   16.939678  ...  254.199997  247.339996  249.009995  244.989441  35560400
2022-12-16   16.864000   17.041000   16.410000   16.570999   16.558958  ...  249.839996  243.509995  244.690002  240.739197  86102000
2022-12-19   16.572001   16.608999   16.145000   16.254000   16.242184  ...  245.210007  238.710007  240.449997  236.567657  29696400
...                ...         ...         ...         ...         ...  ...         ...         ...         ...         ...       ...
2024-12-06  144.600006  145.699997  141.309998  142.440002  142.440002  ...  446.100006  441.769989  443.570007  443.570007  18821000
2024-12-09  138.970001  139.949997  137.130005  138.809998  138.809998  ...  448.329987  440.500000  446.019989  446.019989  19144400
2024-12-10  139.009995  141.820007  133.789993  135.070007  135.070007  ...  449.619995  441.600006  443.329987  443.329987  18469500
2024-12-11  137.360001  140.169998  135.210007  139.309998  139.309998  ...  450.350006  444.049988  448.989990  448.989990  19200200
2024-12-12  137.100006  138.410004  135.800003  137.339996  137.339996  ...  456.164795  449.130005  449.559998  449.559998  20719891

Desired output with each ticker's dataframe separated
separated_df = {'AAPL': aapl_df,
                'MSFT': msft_df,
                'NVDA': nvda_df}

The MultiIndex dataframe also has extra names=['Price', 'Ticker'] columns that I can't seem to get rid of
Code
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

single = ['GOOGL']

df = yf.download(single, 
                 period='2y', 
                 interval='1d',
                 multi_level_index=False)

print(df)

tickers = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'NVDA']
multiple_df = yf.download(tickers, 
                          period='2y', 
                          interval='1d',
                          group_by='Ticker',
                          multi_level_index=False)

print(multiple_df)


You can use pandas loc and a for loop to filter based on each ticker, and save everything in a dictionary.
tickers = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'NVDA']

separated_df = {}
for ticker in tickers:
    tmp = multiple_df.loc[:, ticker].rename_axis(None, axis=1)
    separated_df[ticker] = tmp

You can now call each dataframe using the dictionary
separated_df['AAPL']

                  Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close     Volume
Date                                                                             
2022-12-13  149.500000  149.970001  144.240005  145.470001  143.956161   93886200
2022-12-14  145.350006  146.660004  141.160004  143.210007  141.719696   82291200
2022-12-15  141.110001  141.800003  136.029999  136.500000  135.079514   98931900
2022-12-16  136.690002  137.649994  133.729996  134.509995  133.110229  160156900
2022-12-19  135.110001  135.199997  131.320007  132.369995  130.992508   79592600
2022-12-20  131.389999  133.250000  129.889999  132.300003  130.923218   77432800
2022-12-21  132.979996  136.809998  132.750000  135.449997  134.040421   85928000
2022-12-22  134.350006  134.559998  130.300003  132.229996  130.853943   77852100
2022-12-23  130.919998  132.419998  129.639999  131.860001  130.487823   63814900
2022-12-27  131.380005  131.410004  128.720001  130.029999  128.676834   69007800
2022-12-28  129.669998  131.029999  125.870003  126.040001  124.728355   85438400


Ok found out how. Indexing on MultiIndex
multiple_df.index.name = None
data = {idx: gp.T for idx, gp in multiple_df.T.groupby(level=0)}

separated_df = {}
for ticker in data:
    new_df = data[ticker][ticker]['Close High Low Open Volume'.split()]
    new_df.columns.name = None
    adj_close = data[ticker][ticker]['Adj Close']
    new_df.insert(0, 'Adj Close', adj_close)
    
    separated_df[ticker] = new_df

print(separated_df)


Internally, yfinance is downloading the individual tickers, then merging them with concat.
It might make more sense to loop over the tickers to download them individually rather than merging+splitting:
tickers = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'NVDA']
options = {'period': '2y',
           'interval': '1d',
           'group_by': 'Ticker',
           'multi_level_index': False,
          }
out = {t: yf.download(t, **options) for t in tickers}

If you want to use multiprocessing (which might be faster, or not, depending on the number of tickers):
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

tickers = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'NVDA']
options = {'period': '2y',
           'interval': '1d',
           'group_by': 'Ticker',
           'multi_level_index': False,
          }

pool = ThreadPool(processes=5)

def load_ticker(ticker, *args, **kwargs):
    return yf.download(ticker, **kwargs)

out = {t: pool.apply_async(load_ticker, (t,), kwds=options).get()
       for t in tickers}

Finally, to perform a split with groupby, you could first stack the tickers:
tmp = multiple_df.stack('Ticker')
out = dict(list(tmp.droplevel('Ticker')
                   .groupby(tmp.index.get_level_values('Ticker'))))

